# Ubuntu Linux - Install Packages from Local Repository

Tags: linux, ubuntu, deployment, package, apt

We (my workplace) have an embedded product based around an NVIDIA TK1 which is running a custom build of Ubuntu for ARM. As part of the setup routine for our product, we have a custom script which downloads a large number of packages and archives from the web, extracts and installs them.

Ideally what we are looking to do is to pre-download these packages and archives into a "local" repository so that our product uses known versions which work with our application. Auto-updating of packages is disabled and the end product will rarely have access to the internet anyway, we just want to ensure that the versions of packages used remains the same for EVERY product shipped.

As an example, here are parts of the update script:

```
sudo apt-get install -y linux-firmware
sudo apt-get install -y '.*libxcb.*' libxrender-dev libxi-dev libfontconfig1-dev libudev-dev libx11-dev libx11-xcb-dev libext-dev libgstreamer0.10-dev libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-dev
sudo apt-get install -y gcc-4.9 g++-4.9
sudo apt-get install -y ros-indigo-desktop
# This one is shortened as its a long URL
wget cuda-repo-l4t-r21.1-6-5-prod_6.5-14_armhf.deb
sudo dpk -i cuda-repo-l4t-r21.1-6-5-prod_6.5-14_armhf.deb
```

Obviously, a large number of the packages will have a lot of dependencies so if there is a way of downloading ALL required packages and ALL required dependencies into a local package repository and change my scripts so they are installed from there, that would the ideal.

I'm unsure as which way would be the best way to approach this.

I have had suggestions of installing all packages onto a base product then "cloning" the file system and pushing it onto other modules however I don't really know the pros/cons of doing this.

**UPDATE**

Ok, so I've since found a large number of packages in the `/var/cache/apt/archives/` folder which seem to all relate to what is installed from our script.

Is it feasible/safe to install ALL of these packages using `sudo dpkg -i *.deb`?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/974/how-can-i-install-software-or-packages-without-internet-offline

Answer (score 0):

A good thing would be to use some kind of `debootstrap` to build a custom image and then flash it on the devices.

To cache the `apt-get` there is `apt-cacher`. I haven't tried, but its cache can be freezed.

For the local repositories - `reprepro`.